# Can I Intentionally Disable PCIe Lanes? Or lower PCIe Width?

Tags: linux, pci-express, lspci

I am doing some testing on my server and want to lower the width to my PCIe device (or its PCIe bridge).

In case it is relevant, I figured out how to lower my speed based on the PCI Spec with Linux's setpci and changing the Link Control 2 Register's  "Target Link Speed". This allows me to drop from a 8GT/s to 5GT/s or even 2.5GT/s.

Here is an example of that working:

```
Server:~ # setpci -s 83:04.0 98.w=1:ff
Server:~ # setpci -s 83:04.0 78.w=20:20
Server:~ # ./check_speed_width
  84:00.0 has reported reduced PCIe speed: 2.5GT/s instead of 8GT/s
  bridge device 83:04.0 has reported reduced PCIe speed: 2.5GT/s instead of 8GT/s
Server:~ # setpci -s 83:04.0 98.w=2:ff
Server:~ # setpci -s 83:04.0 78.w=20:20
Server:~ # ./check_speed_width
  84:00.0 has reported reduced PCIe speed: 5GT/s instead of 8GT/s
  bridge device 83:04.0 has reported reduced PCIe speed: 5GT/s instead of 8GT/s
```

Some of my ideas so far to lower width are:

- Maybe I just missed a writable register? Target Link Speed is a register with read and write capabilities. When it comes to the Width registers, I only see read-only registers listed in the PCI spec.
- Maybe there is a way to disable a some of the lanes separate from the PCIe spec?
- I know that stuff can train/initialize to lower widths if it is having problems. So maybe I can inject errors onto a particular lane and cause it to drop the lane?

Comment: I found that the "initiate link width change is implementation
specific". So this may not be something I can do in a general sense.
Based on the pcisig [Understanding PCIe ® 2.0 Bandwidth Management](http://kavi.pcisig.com/developers/main/training_materials/get_document?doc_id=090831b9a2b1210b2822c06e469992d9d028f13d)

Comment: Some server manufacturers have started adding PCIe bifurcation for uses like multiple NVMe drives. So it may be possible to do this in the future via BIOS settings.

Comment: Hey @TaylorSanchez. Apologies for offtopic necro-posting, but can I have your `check_speed_width` script and whatever is the algorithm for computing the PCI register values for link speed reduction?

Comment: @intelfx I don't have access to it anymore. If I remember correctly used mainly python to parse `lspci -vvv` or `lspci -xxx` output. The xxx output would require reading up on the pci spec to understand the registers

Comment: @intelfx I got an old coworker to explain the logic. Essentially you need to compare the the link capability with the link status `LnkCap:` and `LnkSta`. A big catch is, the parent or child devices may have a lower LnkCap causing the entire bus to be slow. You can only be as fast as the slowest LnkCap in the branch. The `lspci -tv` shows you the bus tree. I think using the `x` output was much more consistent to parse than the `vvv`. Writing the script took a good amount of reading lscpi and the pci spec documentation.